# Correct word order of “An article you are a co-writer of”?

Tags: word-order, inversion, formality, formal-language

I am having trouble with the wording of a sentence in a formal letter. I came up with this, but, for me, it feels somewhat twisted and incorrect. How would you pharse this?

> During my research, I found the article "Carbon fiber material in
>   musical instrument making" at ScienceDirect (link) **you are a co-writer of**.

Comment: The wording doesn't strike me an unusual, but I'd say "co-author", probably. Not a native speaker though.

Comment: What @M.A.R. said. Note that [***co-author** is far more common than **co-writer***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=co-writer%2Cco-author&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cco%20-%20writer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cco%20-%20author%3B%2Cc0), and this preference applies equally to "verbified" forms such as ***co-wrote, co-authored***.

Comment: I think it would sound better with a "that" in between the (link) and **you**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine, but some people still complain, particularly in formal writing, about ending a sentence with a preposition. (The injunction against doing so was made up out of nowhere a couple of centuries ago, but a lot of people used to believe in it, and some still do).

An alternative I would suggest is "that you co-wrote".

Comment: Interestingly, *that I co-wrote* [is as common as](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+I+co-wrote%2Cthat+I+co-authored&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20I%20co%20-%20wrote%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20I%20co%20-%20authored%3B%2Cc0) *that I **co-authored*** in the AmE corpus on Google NGrams, but the former doesn't occur often enough to even chart in the BrE corpus. Which reflects my preference as a Brit, but I can't say I particularly *object* to the alternative.

Comment: The GloWbE corpus gives a slightly different picture. There,  _co-authored_ is about 50% more common than _co-wrote_ (474:327) in British sources, but nearly twice as common (682:350) in US sources. In Canadian sources, it's more than twice as common (213:89).

Comment: Yeah - NGram's US/UK classification is pretty flakey, quite apart from the matter of reflecting "representative" samples.